# Error when compiling python code when using ffpyplayer

Tags: python, opencv, pyinstaller

I am packaging my app on Ubunutu using pyinstaller, and `import ffpyplayer` in my code. pyinstaller builds the executable, but when I execute the program I receive this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "hdc.py", line 13, in File
> "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
> File "ffpyplayer/player/init.py", line 10, in File
> "ffpyplayer/player/player.pyx", line 2, in init
> ffpyplayer.player.player ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'ffpyplayer.threading' [42447] Failed to execute script hdc

I am using `ffpyplayer` along with `opencv` to playback a local video file.   Using PyCharm as my IDE and both `ffpyplayer` and `opencv` work flawlessly in the IDE, as well as from the command prompt.  I have tried pyinstaller with and without the `--onefile` option, same result.

How can I resolve this issue? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

so based off this https://github.com/matham/ffpyplayer/issues/59#issuecomment-588044409

In your specfile do:  `import ffpyplayer` and then in your tree line add: `ffpyplayer.dep_bins` to the list. If there's multiple sources your tree would end up looking like: `*[Tree(p) for p in (source1 + source2 + ffpyplayer.dep_bins)]`

edit: there is more you need to add AND to remove.

You also need to add to the datas=[] line in your specfile. There is an example here: https://github.com/matham/filers2/blob/master/packaging/Filers2.spec

So minimally do:
`datas = ['ffpyplayer', 'ffpyplayer.pic','ffpyplayer.threading', 'ffpyplayer.tools', 'ffpyplayer.writer','ffpyplayer.player', 'ffpyplayer.player.clock', 'ffpyplayer.player.core', 'ffpyplayer.player.decoder', 'ffpyplayer.player.frame_queue', 'ffpyplayer.player.player', 'ffpyplayer.player.queue']`

to get it to work you uninstall the gstreamer dependency as per: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6964#issuecomment-790869214
like so: [Kivy Install gone awry - Windows 10 (was working, now not after gstreamer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731922/kivy-install-gone-awry-windows-10-was-working-now-not-after-gstreamer)
after you `python -m pip uninstall kivy.deps.gstreamer`
then compile again with pyinstall and ffpyplayer should work